# Http requests and TCP connections

Tags: http, networking, https, tcp, ip

My understanding so far is that when someone tries to access web page the following happens:

1. HTTP request is formed
2. New socket is opened
3. HTTP request is sent

If everything went OK, the web browser accepts HTTP response and builds DOM tree out of received HTML. If there are any resources missing, new HTTP request needs to be made for each one separately.

Each of those HTTP requests requires opening another socket (establishing new virtual connection with server).

**Q**: How is that efficient? I understand those resources could be located on another host (which would indeed require new TCP connection) but if they are all on the same host wouldn't it be way more efficient to transfer all data within single TCP connection.

Answer (score 5):

> Each of those HTTP requests requires opening another socket (establishing new virtual connection with server).

No it doesn't. HTTP 1.1 uses persistent connections by default, and HTTP 1.0 before it had the unofficial `Connection: keep-alive` header, which accomplished the same thing, nearly twenty years ago.

> Q: How is that efficient?

It isn't, and that's why it doesn't happen.

> I understand those resources could be located on another host (which would indeed require new TCP connection) but if they are all on the same host wouldn't it be way more efficient to transfer all data within single TCP connection.

Yes, and that is what happens by default.